# Spotify API Frequency Analysis JS

Tags: javascript, fft, spotify, frequency, analysis

I'm creating a 3d terrain-like audio visualiser for a school project and I am intending to use the Spotify API to stream music files into the browser rather than  download and upload mp3 files as I think it will be a much smoother experience and will give me some more marks. If any of you are experienced with or understand the Spotify API well I'd appreciate you letting me know if you can analyse frequencies from streamed tracks, as I will be sampling frequencies at intervals to pass through a fast fourier transform. Thanks,

Kit

Answer (score 0):

This appears to not be supported.
You can get audio analysis from Spotify for a track, but it does not give frequency data, as seen here: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/tracks/get-audio-analysis/